# Excel/insert column after every third data column and calculate CV (STDEV/AVERAGE), then calculate average of CVs for that column

Tags: vba, excel

I analyze numerical data in Excel spread sheets, each row contains data which is in triplicate one column after another (left to right, see Excel data set picture). For each row there can be 30-180 columns total (so 10-60 samples in triplicate per row). In addition, there can be 10-180 rows of the data. I want the VB code to insert a column after every third column (starting with column D) and in that new column calculate the CV [=STDEV(D3:F3)/AVERAGE(D3:F3)] for the row values across the three columns (D3/E3/F3), and at the bottom of the inserted column calculate the average of all the CVs for that column (see Processed Excel data set picture). I also want the code to recognize when it has come to the end of the columns "with data" since my data sets have variable numbers of columns (but always in groups of 3) and I also want the code to recognize when it has come to the end on the rows "with data" since the number of rows also varies. Below are pictures of the starting Excel data set and the Processed Excel data set. I looked at many related answered questions that came up in the search, but none fit this application, and I have very little knowledge of writing code. Thank you for the help, it is really appreciated.

[Excel data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJI7L.png)

[Processed Excel data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJG0S.png)

Comment: What are your 'rules' for 'end of data'? An blank/empty cell value in a row or column?

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for looking at this, my end of data rule is a "blank/empty cell value in row or column"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code... just change the sheet name to whatever sheet name you have.

```
Option Explicit

Function STDEV_AVG()
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim iRow    As Integer
Dim iCol    As Integer
Dim iLastrow    As Long
Dim iLastCol    As Long
Dim rng1        As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet5")
    Sheets(ws.Name).Activate
    With ws
        iLastrow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        iLastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).column
    End With

    If iLastCol < 6 Then
        MsgBox "There must be a minimum of 6 columns, else this format seems incorrect!"
    End If

    For iCol = iLastCol + 1 To 7 Step -3
        ws.Cells(1, iCol).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireColumn.Insert (xlShiftToRight)
        Cells(2, iCol) = "StdDev"
        For iRow = 3 To iLastrow
            If Cells(iRow, iCol - 1) <> "" Then
                Set rng1 = ws.Range(Cells(iRow, iCol - 3), Cells(iRow, iCol - 1))
                'ws.Range(Cells(iRow, iCol - 3), Cells(iRow, iCol - 1)).Select
                Cells(iRow, iCol).Formula = "=STDEV.P(" & rng1.Address & ")"
            End If
        Next iRow
        Set rng1 = ws.Range(Cells(3, iCol), Cells(iLastrow, iCol))
        'ws.Range(rng1.Address).Select
        Cells(iLastrow + 1, iCol).Formula = "=Average(" & rng1.Address & ")"
    Next iCol

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, I incorrectly stated I wanted the STDEV, really wanted the CV (STDEV/AVERAGE; STDEV(D3:F3)/AVERAGE(D3:F3)). I am trying to modify your code from calculating STDEV to CV but not having any luck yet. Your help would again be really appreciated.

Comment: Then try replacing "=STDEV.P(" & rng1.Address & ")"    with   "=(STDEV(" & rng1.Address & "))/Average(" & rng1.Address & ")"      This results in STDEV/AVERAGE

Comment: Okay, that worked, the only issue I ran into was when I applied this macro to an Excel file that had a previous macro run on it and left #DIV/0! for values it could not calculate, This macro would not run on those files until I replaced all #DIV/0! with 0.0, and then it ran perfect.

Comment: Need some clarity here... (1) Will you attempt to run this code on a sheet that has already been 'processed'? I thought from your showing the two screen prints, the answer would be no. (2) If any cell (of the three) is blank/empty, then what do you want? (2.a) No formula. or (2.b) exclude blank cell?

Comment: Wayne, my apologizes for not explaining everything, the first screen print "Excel data set" was an output file that had had a formula run on it (to determine concentrations). Sometimes the "Excel data set" file will contain cells with #DIV/0!. So if your code can recognize a cell that contains #DIV/0! and then use "no formula" and leave the cell empty that would be perfect. Thank you again

Comment: So you are saying that: (1) some (or all) of the cells in the input sheet are formulas and not values? and (2) that sometimes the formulas result in errors?
Are there formulas in ALL columns "D" thru "I"? or just some? Where are the formulas?  Yes, I can change the code to look for errors and exclude those cells from the calculation. Anything else I need to know? Will you ever manually change a value in any of the existing cells AFTER the code runs? If not, simple solution.

Comment: Also, if one of your formulas results in an error, can I simply set that cell to empty?